# Why switch case is working weird on enum types in c++?

Tags: c++, debugging, enums, switch-statement, gdb

I tried to debug below cpp code in gdb having an enum variable and accessing it in switch case statement. Here as you can see **vtype** is assigned **var4** so it should go in **case var4**, but it is going in **case var1**. And when I remove the assignments on enum vars then its going in **case var5**.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef enum {
    var1 = 1,
    var2 = 2,
    var3 = 3,
    var4 = 4,
    var5 = 5
} VType;

int main(){
    VType vtype = var4;
    switch(vtype){
    case var1:
        break;
    case var2:
        std::cout << "dummy one";
        break;
    case var3:
        break;
    case var5:
        break;
    case var4:
        //implemented elsewhere
        break;
    default :
        std::cout << "error";
    }
}
```

Here in gdb I tried to print the integer value i.e. **(int)vtype** and **(int)var1** it is showing values 1 and 4 as expected but still it is going in **case var1**. Can someone please explain why is it working like this ?

Comment: OT: You don't need `typedef` in C++, `enum VType { ... };` will define a type. Also, if you set one enumeration name to a value, all the rest will be automatically incremented from that value.

Comment: I guess it's because case var1 and case var4 are identical, there is nothing in both of them.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled? Even if not, it may apply: The `case` do exactly the same thing. The compiler may have simply optimized everything to one branch so that there isn't any information for gdb left to distinguish the cases. You shouldn't 100% trust where the debugger points in the source code. There is no guarantee that it actually is correct. It is a best effort approach. On the other hand, it should always point to the correct assembly instruction.

Comment: Cannot reproduce [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/drsxq7Wo6), likely just insufficient debug line information, especially if you have optimizations enabled.

Comment: **Don't use C++ like C**. There is no need for `typedef` here in c++. Just write `enum VType { // };`

Comment: I think since optimizer noticed that cases 1 3 4 5 do exactly same thing (nothing), it combined this code into single instruction/singe branch. As a result debugger is unable to distinguish those cases when stepping through this code, since there is common code for this cases.

Answer (score 1):

Even with `-O0` specified, the compiler has noticed that some of your cases have the same (empty) body and has merged them. Here is an assembly snippet from Compiler Explorer. The eax register holds your `vtype` variable.

```
    cmp     eax, 5
    ja      .L2                         // Default case if vtype > 5
    mov     eax, eax
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR .L4[0+rax*8] // Index into the jump table below using vtype
                                        // Note how the .L11 label appears multiple times
    jmp     rax

.L4:
    .quad   .L2                         // vtype = 0: default case
    .quad   .L11                        // vtype = 1: empty case
    .quad   .L7                         // vtype = 2: print the "dummy" string
    .quad   .L11                        // vtype = 3: empty case
    .quad   .L11                        // vtype = 4: empty case
    .quad   .L11                        // vtype = 5: empty case

.L2: // print the default string. and exit through L9. L7 is similar.
    mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
    jmp     .L9
.L11: // Do nothing, fall through
    nop
.L9:  // Leave the function. Common exit label for all cases.
    mov     eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple compiler optimizer noticed that cases 1 3 4 5 do exactly same thing (nothing), so it combined this code into single instruction/singe code branch.

As a result debugger is used with such optimization it is unable to distinguish those cases since it always goes through same code machine, when stepping through this code. Debugger symbols are matching machine code to single line number.

Here is simplified godbld showing this nicely: https://godbolt.org/z/YPK6zxPq4
Note no extra optimizations are enabled and compiler applies this optimization.